# Добавление массива в многомерный массив php

Tags: php

Что-то я заработался..) Подскажите пожалуйста, как в конец массива добавить массив? Мне нужно чтобы был такой результат:

```
$arr = array(
   "Иванов" => array(
       "2017-10-31" => 25,
       "2017-11-01" => 50
   ),
   "Петров" => array(
       "2017-10-31" => 11,
       "2017-11-01" => 17
   )
);
```

Я делаю так:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($user); $i++)
            {
                array_push($newData, $user[$i] => array()); //Новый массив данных для пользователя

                $sql = sqlsrv_query($con, "EXEC forUser '".$user[$i]."'");

                while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($sql))
                {
                    if(strcmp($user[$i] == trim($row[3])) == 0)
                    {
                        array_push($newData[$user[$i]], array($row[0] => $row[1]));
                    }
                }
            }
```

Ошибка вот тут `array_push($newData, $user[$i] => array());`

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW)

Что я делаю не так?? Всем заранее большое спасибо!

Comment: У вас ассоциативный массив, array_push() не в тему.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте что-то такое

```
$buf = [];
$buf[$user[$i]] = []; //Если я правильно понимаю - $user[$i] это имя юзера
....
//Ну и дальше работаем с buf[$user[$i]], добавляя в него ваши данные как в массив
```

Это все в общем виде конечно, но надеюсь принцип понятен

Comment: Большое спасибо!